# How do you find the distance while drawing line on mouse vertical axis or horizontal?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web, d3.js

I want to calculate the distance while drawing the line on the vertical axis or horizontal axis. It could show next to the line of how much distance drawn from mousedraw or any other ways. Can someone help me?

```
var width = 400,
          height = 500;

  var data = [10, 15, 20, 25, 30];
  var svg = d3.select("body")
          .append("svg")
          .attr("width", width)
          .attr("height", height)
          .on("mousedown", mousedown)
          .on("mouseup", mouseup);


  var xscale = d3.scale.linear()
          .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
          .range([0, width - 100]);

  var yscale = d3.scale.linear()
          .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
          .range([height / 2, 0]);

  svg.on("mousemove", function() {
     console.log("x - using invert", xscale.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0] - 50));
     console.log("y- using invert", yscale.invert(d3.mouse(this)[1] - 10));
  });

  var x_axis = d3.svg.axis()
          .scale(xscale).orient("bottom");

  var y_axis = d3.svg.axis()
          .scale(yscale).orient("left");;

  svg.append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(50, 10)")
          .call(y_axis);

  var xAxisTranslate = height / 2 + 10;

  svg.append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(50, " + xAxisTranslate + ")")
          .call(x_axis)


  function mousedown() {
     var m = d3.mouse(this);
     line = svg.append("line")
             .attr("x1", m[0])
             .attr("y1", m[1])
             .attr("x2", m[0])
             .attr("y2", m[1]);

     svg.on("mousemove", mousemove);
  }

  function mousemove() {
     var m = d3.mouse(this);
     line.attr("x2", m[0])
             .attr("y2", m[1]);
  }

  function mouseup() {
     svg.on("mousemove", null);
  }
```

Please check the live output I have now: https://jsfiddle.net/anojansith/m38b5fnp/1/

[Image expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVJOn.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might already know the Pythagorean theorem for determining the distance of a straight line; you could implement it like this:

```
Math.sqrt((m[0] - line.attr("x1")) ** 2 + (m[1] - line.attr("y1")) ** 2)
```

I'm referencing your global variable `line` and the local variable `m` for the mouse position. To display this next to the mouse cursor? Well, in `mousedown` you can add a text variable in addition to the line:

```
text = svg.append("text")
        .attr("x", m[0])
        .attr("y", m[1])
        .style("user-select", "none")
```

Then you update the text in `mousemove`, shoving it over to the right of the cursor a little. Also in this case the distance is expressed in the same units as the data, by inverting the scale functions and thereby converted from pixels back into the data units.

```
var dist = Math.sqrt(
        (xscale.invert(m[0]) - xscale.invert(line.attr("x1"))) ** 2 + 
        (yscale.invert(m[1]) - yscale.invert(line.attr("y1"))) ** 2)
text
  .text(dist.toFixed(2))
  .attr("x", m[0] + 10)
  .attr("y", m[1])
```

and remove it in `mouseup`

```
text.remove()
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/anojansith/m38b5fnp/5/ Not working precisely when I move the lines, why?

Comment: I mean line values goes beyond the x-axis and y-axis values. why bro?

Comment: ah ok, so the solution I've given you is the distance in pixels, you want the distance expressed in the same units as the axis, right?

Comment: Yes please, that is the only thing I have been searching for - because my x-axis and y-axis values change dynamically and I do not want it calculates beyond that range, it means it will need to calculate the small object's height or width by using this line (ruler) on the D3.js chart. Thanks, I appreciate, if you can correct that :)

Comment: I coloured in your appended svg in red, this is what the returned math is based on right?  https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/b81sdhw2/

Comment: yes that was the output, I might have placed the code in wrong order may be. But that works on pixel. i would like in based on dynamic axis to measure distance using a line horizontally and vertically.

Comment: ok, this can be done with .invert method of scale.linear ... i'll edit my answer

Comment: here, i forked it: https://jsfiddle.net/geofholbrook/wsbmftxr/